# How to create log file in in tomcat/logs folder

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm using log4j to log in application.

Now the log file is created in the some location, like j:/logs/mylog.log, I want the log file mylog.log to be created in the tomcat/logs foder.

How to set this?

Now current log4j property is as follows

```
log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.fileAppender.datePattern=dd MMM yyyy
log4j.appender.fileAppender.file=/logs/test/parent/LearnFile.log
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set it like this

```
log4j.appender.fileAppender.file=${catalina.base}/logs/mylog.log
```